# NGRX/Store payload type confusion

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have the following actions:

```
export const ActionTypes = {
  CREATE_OH:                  type('[ORDERHEAD] Create Orderhead'),
  MODIFY_SELECTED_OH:    type('[ORDERHEAD] Select Orderhead'),     
};

export class CreateOHAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.CREATE_OH

  constructor(public payload: OrderHead[]) { }
}

export type Actions
  =   CreateOHAction
  |   SelectOHAction;
```

With the following base reducer setup

```
export interface State {
  orderids: string[];
  entities: { [orderID: string]: OrderHead };
  selectedOhID: string | null;
};

// Set initial state to empty
const initialState: State = {
  orderids : [],
  entities: {},
  selectedOhID: null,

};
export function OHreducer(state = initialState, action: orderhead_imp.Actions):  State{
      switch(action.type){

        case orderhead_imp.ActionTypes.CREATE_OH: 
            let orders = action.payload;
            let newOrders = orders.filter(orderhead => !state.entities[orderhead.orderID]);

            let newOrderIds = newOrders.map(orderhead => orderhead.orderID);
            let newOrderHeadEntities = newOrders.reduce((entities: { [orderID: string]: OrderHead }, orderhead: OrderHead) => {
              return Object.assign(entities, {
                [orderhead.orderID]: orderhead
              });
            }, {});

            return {
              orderids: [ ...state.orderids, ...newOrderIds ],
              entities: Object.assign({}, state.entities, newOrderHeadEntities),
              selectedOhID: state.selectedOhID
              };

        default:
            return state;

    };
}
```

This works fine, however, if I introduce another action:

```
export class SelectOHAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.MODIFY_SELECTED_OH 

  constructor(public payload: string) { }
}
```

Notice, the payload **for this action only** is string, as soon as this saved, or tried to compile, typescript now states: **"filter does not exisit on type string|OrderHead[]"**

Now if I go into my reducer, and add a new case:

```
case orderhead_imp.ActionTypes.MODIFY_SELECTED_OH: {
 return {
  orderids:  state.orderids,
  entities: state.entities,
  selectedOhID: action.payload
};
}
```

I get the typescript errors when mapping action.payload of:

Throws the TS error **"string|OrderHead[] is not assignable to type string"**

Obviously in both cases the payload has a different data structure, do I need to change my code any other way to ensure each case is picking up the correct type for action.payload?

**Update**

So if in my actions I define the payload as "any" instead of "string" it seems to compile and work without issue, however this seems *very* hacky (and not the expected behaviour)

```
export class SelectOHAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.MODIFY_SELECTED_OH 

  constructor(public payload: any) { }
}
```

Comment: In your state try `selectedOhID: string|null` to just `selectedOhID: string`

Comment: No, I tried this first of all, but if I set type in my reducer of any for selectedOhID it still fails, its a type checking error from the payload value defined in actions, not an error from the reducer type definitions.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? There was a breaking change (arguably a bug fix) in typescript 2.1+ that affects string literals (and therefore discriminated unions).

Comment: 2.1.5, is this a known issue or is there now a fix?

Comment: Any update about this issue? I am using ngrx store and effects 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Typescript >2.1 and the type util of ngrx.

With typescript 2.1 and above now you can simply define actions as

```
export const CREATE_OH: '[ORDERHEAD] Create Orderhead';
export class CreateOHAction implements Action {
   type = CREATE_OH

   constructor(public payload: OrderHead[]) { }
}
```

Now everywhere you used `item.ActionTypes.CREATE_OH`, replace it with `item.CREATE_OH`. The types will flow as expected with typescript 2.1

Comment: I have the exact same issue as the original post has. I already did this change to my actions and the problem remains the same.